# Why are characters of algebraic groups interesting?

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, characters, motivation

Are characters of an algebraic group the same thing as one-dimensional representations? Since a character of $G$ is $\rho:G\to \Bbb{G}_m\cong \text{GL}(1,\Bbb C)$ it seems these are the same thing? Am I right?

Why are characters interesting?

Comment: It seems you understand the definition, they are indeed 1-dim reps. I think the question you really want is your last sentence"why are characters interesting?" You might want to edit the q/title so it asks the more fundamental question, to attract better answers (also the soft-q tag)

Comment: @mdave16 Thanks for the advice

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)) they give a concrete example. Otherwise $G^{ab} = G/[G,G]$ is interesting.

Comment: It is a corollary of a paper by rosenlicht that $k[G]^* = k^*X(G)$, so once you know that $G$ is semisimple, we get that units in $k[G]$ is just $k^*$ which might seem interesting in itself. Look at this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57352/are-units-of-rings-of-functions-on-algebraic-varieties-finitely-generated-mod.

Comment: There is another notion of character that tends to be of more interest for semisimple algebraic groups. Namely, any (let's say finite-dimensional for simplicity) rational representation has a "formal character" attached to it, which is basically the image of the representation in the Grothendieck group. While these do not in general determine the representation (except in characteristic $0$) the determination of them for irreducibles is a fundamental problem in the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The character group $X(G)$ of a connected, reductive group $G$ is as interesting as the character group of its radical $A = \mathscr R(G)$.  Here $A$ is the unique maximal torus lying in the center of $G$.  It is the connected component of the center of $G$.

The result I'm getting at is that the restriction map $X(G) \rightarrow X(A)$ is an injection, and its image is a subgroup of finite index of $X(A)$.

Proof: Let $G_D$ be the derived group of $G$.  Then $G_D \cap A$ is finite, and the product map $(x,y) \mapsto xy^{-1}$ induces an isomorphism of algebraic groups

$$(G_D \times A)/N \rightarrow G$$

where $N = \{ (x,x) : x \in G_D \cap A \}$.  We can identify the character group of $(G_D \times A)/N$ with those characters of $G_D \times A$ which are trivial on $N$.  Since $N$ is finite, this is a finite index subgroup of $X(G_D \times A)$.    Now $X(G_D \times A) = X(G_D) \times X(A)$, with $X(G_D)$ the trivial group: any semisimple group such as $G_D$ coincides with its derived group, making any character on it trivial.  The composition of all these maps

$$X(G) \xrightarrow{\cong} X(G_D \times A/N) \rightarrow X(G_D \times A) \xrightarrow{\cong} X(A)$$

is the restriction map.  $\blacksquare$

So characters of $G$ can be identified with characters of a torus.

More generally, if $G$ is defined over a field $F$, then restriction induces an isomorphism of $X(G)_F$, the subgroup of $X(G)$ consisting of characters which are defined over $F$, with a subgroup of finite index of $X(A_G)$, where $A_G$ is the unique maximal $F$-split subtorus of the center of $G$.

Comment: Very nice explanation of this. You might find my comment on the other kind of character interesting (I left that as a comment on the question).

Comment: I have never heard of that before.  Where can I read more about this?

Comment: They are covered in for example Jantzen's book (as much as was known when it was written more than 10 years ago). They are analogous to the formal characters one considers for representations of Lie algebras.